# Q&A minigame structure

Tags: java, object-oriented

I've decided to improve / test my knowledge so far, as I haven't coded in Java for a while now.  Is there anything I can improve in my code?  The OOP structure?  The code itself?  Useless code?

Main.java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class Main {

        /**
         * A Simple question-and-answer game based on points.
         * @author Jony
         */

        /**
         * Objects
         */

        static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        static QuestionHandler handler = new QuestionHandler();
        static boolean gameIsActive = true;

        /**
         * @main
         */

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.println("Welcome to Question & Answer game.");
            String answer;

            /**
             * Game loop
             */

            while (gameIsActive) {

                /**
                 * If you're NOT in a question, system will generate
                 * a new question, and set inQuestion = true.
                 */

                if (!handler.inQuestion) {
                    handler.generateQuestion();
                }
                else {
                    answer = console.nextLine();
                    if (isset(answer)) {
                        handler.answerQuestion(answer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

        /**
         * isset
         * Checks if a string was set, and is NOT empty ("")
         *
         * @param string    The scanner input.
         * @return boolean
         */

        private static boolean isset(String string) {
            return (string != "");
        }
    }
```

QuestionHandler.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

    class QuestionHandler {

        public static boolean inQuestion = false;
        private static Question currentQnA;
        private static ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
        private static Random rand = new Random();
        private static int points = 0;

        public QuestionHandler() {

            /**
             * Initialize questions
             */

             questions.add(new Question("What language is this programmed in?", "java"));
             questions.add(new Question("What is php?", "hypertext"));
             questions.add(new Question("Who is daniel?", "someguy"));

        }

        /**
         * generateQuestion
         * Sets a random index out of the size of the arraylist.
         *
         * @return void
         */

        public static void generateQuestion() {
            int size = questions.size();
            int index = rand.nextInt(size);
            setQuestion(index);
        }

        /**
         * answerQuestion
         * Player attempts at answering the question...
         *
         * @return void
         */

        public static void answerQuestion(String input) {
            String answer = currentQnA.getAnswer();
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)) {
                awardCorrectAnswer();
            }
            else {
                incorrectAnswer();
            }
        }

        /**
         * setQuestion
         * set the new generated question, make user inQuestion = true
         *
         * @return void
         */

        private static void setQuestion(int index) {
            currentQnA = questions.get(index);
            inQuestion = true;
            System.out.println(currentQnA.getQuestion());
        }

        /**
         * awardCorrectAnswer
         * Award correct answer & get out of the question.
         *
         * @return void
         */

        private static void awardCorrectAnswer() {
            points++;
            System.out.println("You have answered correctly! Won 1 point");
            System.out.println("You now have " + points + " points.");
            inQuestion = false;
        }

        /**
         * incorrectAnswer
         * Take 1 point out of the user, for being clueless & get out of the question.
         *
         * @return void;
         */

        private static void incorrectAnswer() {
            points--;
            System.out.println("Wrong answer! you lost 1 point.");
            System.out.println("You now have " + points + " points.");
            inQuestion = false;
        }       
    }
```

Question.java:

```
class Question implements QnAInterface {

    /**
     * @author Jony <artemkller@gmail.com>
     */

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public Question(String question, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return this.answer;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `QuestionHandler`, everything is `static`.  That means that you are using `QuestionHandler` more as a namespace than a class.  The usual approach is to use the **singleton pattern** instead:

```
class QuestionHandler {
    private static final QuestionHandler instance = new QuestionHandler();

    private Question currentQuestion;
    private List<Question> questions;
    private Random rand;
    private int points;

    public static QuestionHandler getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private QuestionHandler() { ... }
    public void generateQuestion() { ... }
    ... // etc.
}
```

There should be **no side-effects in setters and getters**.  By convention, setters and getters do just that.  In addition to setting and getting, feel free to do whatever it takes to maintain the object in a self-consistent state.  However, anything else you do, such as `System.out.println()` in `.setQuestion()`, would be considered surprising.

I would push the **responsibility to decide whether an answer is correct** into the `Question` class.  That would give you the flexibility to have questions with multiple correct answers.

```
class Question {
    public Question(String question, String answer) { ... }
    public String getQuestion() { ... }
    public boolean isCorrectAnswer(String answer) { ... }
}
```

I think you've **broken up the problem excessively**, creating unnecessary complications.  There shouldn't need to be a separate class called `Main`.  The fact that the `Main` class has a non-descriptive name is a bad sign.  Also, there's too much in class variables (which act like global variables and are therefore bad) that could just be local.

**Suggested `QuestionHandler`:**

```
public class QuestionHandler {
    private List<Question> questions;
    private Random rand;
    private Question currentQuestion;
    private int points;

    public static QuestionHandler instance = new QuestionHandler();

    public static QuestionHandler getInstance() {
        return QuestionHandler.instance;
    }

    private QuestionHandler() {
        this.questions = Arrays.asList(new Question[] {
            new Question("What language is this programmed in?", "java"),
            new Question("What is php?", "hypertext"),
            new Question("Who is daniel?", "someguy")
        });
        this.rand = new Random();
        this.points = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasMoreQuestions() {
        return true;
    }

    public Question nextQuestion() {
        int index = rand.nextInt(questions.size());
        return this.currentQuestion = this.questions.get(index);
    }

    public Question getQuestion() {
        return this.currentQuestion;
    }

    public int getPoints() {
        return this.points;
    }

    public void handleAnswer(String answer) {
        if (this.currentQuestion.isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
            this.points++;
            this.output("You have answered correctly! Won 1 point");
        } else {
            this.points--;
            this.output("Wrong answer! You lost 1 point");
        }
        this.output("You now have " + this.points + " points.");
    }

    private void output(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Question & Answer game.");
        QuestionHandler handler = QuestionHandler.getInstance();
        loop: while (handler.hasMoreQuestions()) {
            Question q = handler.nextQuestion();
            handler.output(q.getQuestion());
            String answer;
            do {
                if (!input.hasNext()) { break loop; }
                answer = input.nextLine();
            } while (answer.isEmpty());
            handler.handleAnswer(answer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Suggested `Question`:**

```
class Question {
    private final String question;
    private final String answer;

    public Question(String question, String answer) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }

    public boolean isCorrectAnswer(String answer) {
        return this.answer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strcuture your classes in packages.

use `final` in this cases

```
 private static ArrayList<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

I think it is not necessary to have [DTO](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) behind an interface.

Avoid redundant comments as

```
/**
         * Objects
         */
```

This comment adds no more information then code itself. And  read [how to use javadoc coments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

And i would separate QuestionHandler and Main into 
**Main** - contains only input/output and QnA game initialization
**QuestionRepository** - Place where questions are retrieved from (this is the place you should use interface)
and **QuestionGame** - place where to put logic of you applicaiton.

And one last thing - Do not output Strings directly in your game. You can set output writer (which is initialized in Main) to your game class and then write through it.